# Windows 7 resolution on a retina macbook pro

Tags: windows-7, resolution, display-settings, macbook-pro-retina

I installed Windows 7 on my Macbook Pro with retina display. Is there any way of making a resolution smaller than 2880 x 1800 fill the whole screen? For any resolution I select, it is displayed at actual size, so letter boxing occurs, rather than being upscaled. I know I can change the DPI to make text and some things larger, but I would rather just have a scaled up version of another resolution. Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is leaving the resolution at full and setting the DPI to something custom. According to [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_displays_by_pixel_density#Apple), you'll want the DPI at 220 pixels per inch.